# Simple explanation why a 5th degree equation is unsolvable by radicals.

Tags: polynomials

Why is a polynomial equation of degree >= 5 unsolvable by radicals?
Is it possible to give an intuitive, possible analogy-based explanation,
in one short sentence, of what really happens?

Comment: What really happens is that there is a smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is closed under the operation of taking radicals, and for each $n > 4$, there are rational polynomials of degree $n$ whose roots are not in that field.  This fact is typically proved using techniques from Galois theory.  At any rate, if you want a longer one-sentence explanation, your question would be more appropriate at http://math.stackexchange.com or one of the other sites listed in the FAQ.

Comment: A one sentence sentence which is useful to remember in this context is that the fact that a general 5th degree polynomials is not solvable by radicals is very related to the fact that the group of permutations on 5 elements is not a solvable group. 

Comment: I guess this is exactly the origin of the term "solvable group"

Comment: ..I was a Flower of the mountain yes when I put the rose in my hair like the Andalusian girls used or shall I wear a red yes and how he kissed me under the Moorish wall and I thought well as well him as another and then I asked him with my eyes to ask again yes and then he asked me would I yes to say yes my mountain flower and first I put my arms around him yes and drew him down to me so he could feel my breasts all perfume yes and his heart was going like mad and yes I said yes I will Yes. 

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible.

Comment: +1! may you earn money so easily as you got points in this answer! 